Multiprocessing of multiple img files to text using OCR
I have more than 100k image files which I need to process into text. Doing conventional for loop takes a lot of time on my device, so I decided to run the code on an azure instance which has 8 cores of CPU and 32 GB ram. I tried to make the code parallel with he help of multiprocessing but it doesn't seem to speed up the process at all (or by a significant much). Earlier I was running this my local laptop with 4 cores (but the code was not made parallel).
I wish to process multiple files at once, i.e use the different available cores to get a 8x speed (I know in practice we won't get 8x, but I'm just writing for reference.). On a side note, I currently have an Apple MacBook Pro with 16 ores and 32 GB RAM as a local device as well, if we can manage to use that to speed up then that'll be great as well.
Also if possible, can someone suggest me the machine configuration which I should use either on Azure or AWS, which can actually give me a huge gain in time. Because at the current speed I think it requires more than 300hrs.
The code which I am running is as follows:
code :
import os
import easyocr
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing

# Use 'spawn' start method for multiprocessing to avoid CUDA issues
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)

# Initialize the EasyOCR reader with GPU support outside the function to avoid reloading the model multiple times
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=True)  # Set gpu=True to use GPU

def ocr_and_extract_text(image_path):
    try:
        # Load and process the image for OCR
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        # Convert the image to grayscale (optional, based on your OCR model requirements)
        image = image.convert('L')

        # Perform OCR using EasyOCR
        extracted_text = reader.readtext(image_path, detail=0)
        extracted_text = ' '.join(extracted_text)  # Join list into a single string
        return extracted_text
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {image_path}: {e}")
        return 'ERROR'

def process_images_in_parallel(csv_file, output_text_csv, num_workers=None):
    # Read the CSV file containing image paths and labels
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    
    # Add a new column to store the extracted text
    data['extracted_text'] = ''

    # Create a list of image paths
    image_paths = data['image_path'].tolist()

    # Use ProcessPoolExecutor to parallelize the OCR
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
        results = list(tqdm(executor.map(ocr_and_extract_text, image_paths), total=len(image_paths), desc="Processing images"))

    # Update the DataFrame with the extracted text
    for image_path, extracted_text in zip(image_paths, results):
        data.loc[data['image_path'] == image_path, 'extracted_text'] = extracted_text

    # Save the results to a new CSV file
    data.to_csv(output_text_csv, index=False)


def main():

    output_folder = '/parallel_img_out'
    output_text_csv = os.path.join(output_folder, 'extracted_texts.csv')
    input_csv = os.path.join(output_folder, 'output_labels_huoston.csv')

    # Check the label counts (not required but useful for debugging)
    data = pd.read_csv(input_csv)
    label_counts = data['label'].value_counts()
    print('label_counts', label_counts)

    # Get the number of available CPU cores
    num_cores = os.cpu_count()
    print(f"Number of available cores: {num_cores}")
    
    # Process images using parallelism across multiple cores
    process_images_in_parallel(input_csv, output_text_csv, num_workers=num_cores - 1)

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


You need to profile the code to know what is the bottleneck on the target machine. For example, if the code is memory-bound, then more core will not make the code significantly faster (this is why it is important to pick a machine fitting your needs and also why profiling is even more important than it seems). The problem is generally shared resources (memory, GPU, etc.)

Here, the OCR seems to be tune to use your GPU which is already a parallel device running parallel code (called kernels). Running more (parallel) kernel from more processes does not make computations faster (assuming one kernel fully use the GPU). In fact, it generally tends to make this slower. You can disable the use of the GPU to check this hypothesis.

@JérômeRichard, Hey Richard. Thanks for your advice, I think the code is IO bound. i.e the GPU is if I switch off the GPU, then I guess the code will not call the GPU and hence I can make use of the multiple cores better? Do you mean this?

I am thinking, if I can make all the cores work the exact same thing, can this not be made parallel? Like I want each core to pick an image and process it independently. So I can maybe get 8 cores processing 8 different images at once? Am I saying something which will not work? I don't know much of how system's work. Can you suggest me a guide on how to profile my code. I'll read and try it out. Or else I'll search web, Thanks.

If the GPU is not used anymore, you should see a better scalability assuming it was the bottleneck, but this does not means the code will be faster in the end. This is definitively something to test. GPUs are generally faster than CPU for SIMT-friendly computing tasks assuming the code is well optimized for them.

For profiling, this is a complex topic but a good start is to check the task manager of your target OS (there are a lot of tool on Linux to check the IO bandwidth, GPU usage, per-core CPU one, network). Tools are often OS dependent (especially low-level profiling and IOs). For the GPU, there is Nsight (and the old nvvp) on Nvidia GPU. For x86-64 CPUs and RAM, there is Vtune. Tools like this require advanced privilege (which is expected to track what is happening on the hardware, but not always possible to get). There are also basic python profilers like line-profiler for the CPU part.
